# Report in Google Play Console with crash in libGLESv2_mtk.so

Tags: android, webview, google-play-console, android-native-library

```
I see crash report with native stack like this in the Google Play Console:

**#00  pc 0x0000000000142eb0  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
#00  pc 0x000000000008560f  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_enter code heremtk.so
#00  pc 0x000000000004e87b  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
#00  pc 0x00000000000861c5  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
#00  pc 0x000000000008655f  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so (glClear)
#00  pc 0x000000000002c2ed  /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_meow.so (MEOW::meow_call_ddk_gl_2_glClear(unsigned int))
      #00  pc 0x0000000002d59a6f  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x0000000002d2d1c5  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x0000000002d2dc9f  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x0000000002d2da2f  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x0000000002d2d8c9  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x0000000002d2d83d  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x0000000002c99b47  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x000000000223b189  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x000000000223b9b9  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x000000000184f827  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x000000000223da77  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x000000000223ae9b  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x000000000223abef  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x000000000223aadf  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x0000000002195ef9  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x00000000022309fd  /data/app/~~d83lw_YrzoAtUPAKGWYbjw==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_511209730-GjEIgDuST31-hubNOyffqA==/base.apk!libmonochrome.so
      #00  pc 0x00000000000807b3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*))
      #00  pc 0x0000000000039d83  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread)**
```

- So far, I haven't been able to reproduce this bug / problem / crash
- And I found that this crash`enter code here` only occurs in the Philippines country, and the android system is 9.0 and above.
  [country img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdlGo.png)
  [cpu img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG1Gf.png)
  [system img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zyo8.png)